# Magento 2 .gitignore template for new project

Tags: magento2, git

I've installed `magento2` via composer. I couldn't find any information about common gitignore files for magento2 and the the file structure is still strange to me.

Can someone share a common gitignore template? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that project was created using

`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .`

take [this .gitignore](https://github.com/magento/magento2-community-edition/blob/master/.gitignore) and put into your project root. It also makes sense to add `/update` and `/phpserver` to ignore list.

Another option:

1. Download this Magento 2 project https://github.com/magento/magento2-community-edition (if you do it via `git clone` make sure to execute `rm -rf .git` just after that)
2. Run `composer update` in the Magento root
3. Initialize new git repository in the root of Magento
4. Almost all core files/directories are already added to the root `.gitignore`, but it is better to add the following 2 as well `/update` and `/phpserver` (just add these 2 lines to .gitignore)
5. Add all untracked files to git and commit them (should be only 3 files, all other are already added to `.gitignore` in the root of Magento.)
6. Start development of your modules as usual (put them under `app/code/YourCompanyName/YourModuleName`), now you will have only your custom code in your git repository

Comment: thanks, but when I installed magento2 via composer there was no gitignore file in the root

Comment: have you used `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <installation directory name>` ?

Comment: yes: `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .`

Comment: so it will be ok to copy the one here: https://github.com/magento/magento2-community-edition/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: Yes, should be good. Updated response. Probably this project is not intended for developers developers, which is strange. Will try to find out.

Comment: Could you explain the reasons of including those `.htaccess` files?

Comment: This will allow to modify them and save modifications in your repository. If not needed in your case, then just remove those lines after `/vendor`

Comment: I rephrase my question: why would you like to modify those files?
Shouldn't this be done in, for example: `/pub/media/.htaccess` and not the one in vendor directory? or am I missing something here?

Comment: @ruuter Is that possible to override `/vendor/magento/magento2-base/.htaccess` with the `.htaccess` located in the root of the project or in some other way?

Comment: Isn't your project directory just a copy of `vendor/magento/magento2-base`?
It should be there only for project initialization, I think. Does .htaccess even have any meaning below Document Root, which should be your `pub` directory.

Comment: It seems having `pub` as `Document Root` is optional, in which case .htaccess files elsewhere would make sense, but IMHO best practice is to keep as much as you can out of public path.

Comment: Additionally, take a look at `vendor/.htaccess`. Even if you don't have pub as doc root,  this file denies all access to anything under vendor directory, including those you listed in you answer. This means browser never sees those and there should be no point to modify. Not to mention next update will overwrite them. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ruuter Makes sense, thank you for such a good point. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: `vendor/magento/magento2-base/.gitignore` does not ignore core files, unlike this one https://github.com/magento/magento2-community-edition/blob/master/.gitignore . I suppose it will be added automatically in scope of future releases of M2

Comment: Anyone help how can i solve the below error : https://snag.gy/35sFTe.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Your `.gitignore` should depend on your **deployment process**. If you use composer install in production then it makes sense to have the vendor folder ignored, but it is very risky:

http://www.letscodejavascript.com/v3/blog/2014/03/the_npm_debacle

If you don't have some other strategies for deployments I would **commit the vendor folder** and not run composer in production.

Also I removed **grunt** folder from gitignore, imo it should be tracked because you have changes to themes.js file etc.

Answer (score 6):

I normally use the following website to generate my gitignore:

https://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: probably better as a comment but one of the best resources I've found from here so thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

For my magneto2 projects I had used git ignore from.

https://dev2devs.com/magento-tips-and-tricks-for-developers-and-server-admins/

Comment: link is broken can you copy / paste here please