# Magento 2 Enterprise: Create New Module in vendor directory

Tags: magento-enterprise, module, magento2, composer

I tried to create new module in `vendor` directory in Magento Enterprise 2.0.0.
The module could not be loaded after I ran the Magento `setup:upgrade`.

If I move my files to the `app/code` directory, the module will be set up successfully.

For Magento 2 Enterprise edition, all modules are in `vendor` directory but Community edition uses `app/code` directory. I wonder if it is possible to create custom module in the `vendor` directory. If yes, what are the differences between creating a custom module in `app/code` and `vendor`.

`vendor/Test/Testing/registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Testing',
    __DIR__ );
```

`vendor/Test/Testing/composer.json`

```
{   "name": "test/testing",   "description": "Testing",   "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"   },   "type": "magento2-module",   "version": "0.1.0",   "license": [
    "proprietary"   ],   "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Test\\Testing\\": ""
    }   } }
```

`vendor/Test/Testing/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Testing" setup_version="0.1.0">
    </module> </config>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need to keep Enterprise modules in vendor directory ?

Comment: Sorry, I does not understand what you mean because I downloaded the Magento 2 Enterprise package and all modules were stored in the vendor directory no matter it is core module or Enterprise module. Even Magento framework is stored in vendor directory. No app/code directory existed in the original package.

Comment: Might I ask what the "psr-4" item in your composer.json does? We use packaging but we have our own GitLab so we have to code in vendor as well, however my code isn't recognized. I can instantiate my class from Magento core modules but Cron does not work. I think it has to do with autoloading, my files aren't being read. I have a class `Company\Reviews\Cron\Check` in file `/vendor/company/Reviews/Cron/Check.php` and I have a cronjob like `Company\Reviews\Cron\Check` but in database `cron_schedule` it just says "Class Company\Reviews\Cron\Check does not exist"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Custom modules should not be developed in `vendor` directory. Copy content from `vendor/magento/magento2-base` to the root of the project, create custom `.gitignore` as described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90952/697) and initialize new git repository. Then develop custom module under `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName`.

Later, when you decide to distribute the module, it will have to be [packaged and published](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/package_module.html). When someone will buy/install your module, it will be automatically installed by composer to `vendor` directory of their project.